# Alamofire "Ambiguous reference to member 'download(_:method:parameters:encoding:headers:to:)'"

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to my code migrate Swift 2 to Swift 3 and I could not find the solution for Alamofire.download function.

How can I migrate Alamofire download function with return part?

My code:

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, url, destination: { temporaryURL, response in
            if let name = response.suggestedFilename {
                if fileName == nil {
                    fileName = name
                } else {
                    fileName = fileName! + "." + NSString(string: name).pathExtension
                }
                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: dataPath.appendingPathComponent(fileName!).path!) {
                    let tempName: NSString = fileName!
                    fileName = tempName.deletingPathExtension + "_copy." + tempName.pathExtension
                }
            }
            return dataPath.appendingPathComponent(fileName!)
        })
```

Comment: Have you update you pod because with swift3 you need to use Alamofire 4, So are you working with Alamofire 4?

Comment: Yes I updated Alamofire to latest version.

Comment: This method signature is changed,I have already answer for this check here   http://stackoverflow.com/a/41136919/6433023

Comment: Reply here if this will helps you or not.

Comment: I am trying to migrate it with your referance solution but right now I could not convert it :(

Comment: Are you getting any error, can you update your question with your tried and where your facing issue with it.

Comment: in download part I am returning value but new version there is no change to return any value. How can I get this value (dataPath.appendingPathComponent(fileName!))?

Comment: Check my answer you need to return like this way tuple now so return it this way `return (dataPath.appendingPathComponent(fileName!), [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])`

Comment: Thanks for your all help Nirav. I have one more question. in .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in is there any way to get bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead values? or in latest version it is giving only progress.fractionCompleted?

Comment: Welcome mate :),I have search on document don't find any thing, Have you try by writing `progress.` is xcode suggesting any thing other then `fractionCompleted`?

Comment: Yes I found the solution. Thanks for all your help :) print("fractionCompleted: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")                
     print("completedUnit: \(progress.completedUnitCount)")
     print("totalUnitCount: \(progress.totalUnitCount)")

Comment: Yes I will vote it :)

Comment: Thanks for the detail mate :)