# Alamofire Not Downloading PDFs

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to download PDFs to the documents directory. The request is successful, but the file doesn't exist in the documents directory after the request is finished.

```
let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)

let documentsDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
let userDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentsDirectory, userDomainMask, true)

if paths.first != nil 
{

    Alamofire.download("http://www.test.com/pdfs/sample.pdf", to: destination).responseData 
    { response in
        if response.result.isFailure
        {
            print("\(response.error!)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you know that its not on the document directory?

Comment: @hasan83 I've checked the Documents directory of the app, in the simulator, in Mac OSX Terminal.

Comment: @bkhosh2 May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/41136560/6433023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with me:

```
let fileExtension: String = fileUrl!.pathExtension
let documentURL: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let filePath = documentURL.appendingPathComponent("\(disk_file_name!).\(fileExtension)")

let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
     return (filePath, [.removePreviousFile])
}

Alamofire.download(URL(string: fileUrl)!, to: destination) ...
```

Comment: I've tried your code. The request completes successfully, but unfortunately, there are still no PDFs in the Documents directory.

Comment: Why you just try to check if its there by code. and that it. maybe there is something else preventing you to find it. thats most probably. but it saved on the right place.

Comment: Does it affect the result if ``filePath`` URL is being encoded? For example, white space in the file path, " ", is being changed to "%20".

Comment: if you are asking if its effect the downloading process. it doesn't.